# System services not available to Activities before onCreate

Tags: android, interface

I have a recycler view in my activity. I implement an Interface in this activity that has to show keyboard when the user, touching a specific item in recycler view and send item position item that user touched into Activity.
This is my Interface:

```
public interface ReplyAction {
  void onEvent(Context context , int courseId);
}
```

This is my interface method that i called in acivity:

```
 @Override
  public void onEvent(final Context mContext, int courseId) {

    replyTo = courseId;
    etMessage = (EditText) ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.etMessage);

    etMessage.setFocusable(true);

    //Show Keyboard to user
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(mContext.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
  }
```

but I will get this error:

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: codenevisha.com.apps.learningmanagementsystem, PID: 7098
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
                      at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5774)
                      at codenevisha.com.apps.learningmanagementsystem.activity.ActivityCourseChat.onEvent(ActivityCourseChat.java:547)
                      at codenevisha.com.apps.learningmanagementsystem.adapter.chatAdapter$1.onClick(chatAdapter.java:240)
```

This is Where I call OnEvent Method that is in my recycler view adapter:

```
@Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    String question;
    String answer;

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {

      case 1: //For item message text left

        question = chatArray.get(position).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumQuestion();
        answer = chatArray.get(position).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumAnswer();

        ViewHolderLeftText vLText = (ViewHolderLeftText) holder;
        vLText.txtQuestion.setText(question);
        if (!answer.equals("")) {
          if (chatArray.get(position).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumAUser().equals(G.userId)) {
            //This Answer is prepared by this user
            vLText.answerLayout.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.my_message_background_color));
          }
          vLText.txtAnswer.setText(answer);

          //Handling reply message to this message
          vLText.imgReplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              ActivityCourseChat a = new ActivityCourseChat();
              a.onEvent(mContext , chatArray.get(position).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumId());

            }
          });
        }
        break;

      case 2: //For item message image left
        ViewHolderLeftImage vLImage = (ViewHolderLeftImage) holder;

        //Handling reply message to this message
        vLImage.imgReply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            ActivityCourseChat a = new ActivityCourseChat();
            a.onEvent(mContext ,chatArray.get(position).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumId());

          }
        });
        break;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace. Also, what calls `onEvent()`, and where is that code?

Comment: I added rest of codes to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActivityCourseChat a = new ActivityCourseChat();
```

**NEVER** create an instance of an activity yourself. Delete both occurrences of this line. Then, get your `ActivityCourseChat` instance some other way. For example, if this `RecyclerView.Adapter` is being used by `ActivityCourseChat`, pass in the `ActivityCourseChat` instance via a constructor parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your simple and exact answer.But can I ask you to explain why this is too bad to create an instance of an activity by myself?

Comment: @Ehsan: Because it does not work. The activity will not be properly initialized.